# Как настроить ширину UITextField по содержимому? Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, apple

Как настроить ширину UITextField по содержимому? Swift 5

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, как у вас в интерфейсе это текстовое поле будет расположено. Нужно изначально исходить от этого.

Как вариант - добавить 2 констрейнта для UITextField:

[image: xCode image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В зависимости от количества текста поле будет менять свой размер относительно центра. Но есть предел, после какого-то количества символов будут обрезаны края (сколько - зависит от размера шрифта, типа и модели устройства и настройки масштабирования).

Если текст должен переносится по строчкам - [использовать UILabel](https://skalolaskovy.ru/xcode/551-uilabel-vertical-align)